# Can I stop BIND from sending response code for bad queries?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I am running an authorative bind dns server. I'm following all the recommended practices and my server is authorative only (none-recursive) with rate-limiting enabled.

BIND responds to queries for none-authorative zones with REFUSE code. Rate-limiting is doing it's job preventing my server from participating in any large scale udp amplification attack, however, I would prefer to eliminate any and all responses for zones which I am not authorative.

Is there configuration option for this?

Comment: Eliminating all responses may not yield the results you expect: this does not prevent the client to try again, on the contrary it forces the client to ask again because it does not receive a reply and can't know where the problem is on the network, so it has to send it again. You will always get traffic for zones you are not authoritative, this is background noise. If it hits really high levels (no point of running against every single one) and/or from small number of clients, you may want instead to just block those clients IP addresses... which can be difficult if it is Google public DNS...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The client won't try again because it's just bots trying to elicit my server with spoofed IP packets. They expect my server to return a response to the victim. When I get a query for '.' it's very clear it's not a legitimate request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not responding in the exact scenario that you depict in the question (spoofed query in a potential amplification attack, alternatively probing whether your server is usable in such an attack) would be ok as no resolver is actually waiting for your response, the issue is that not responding to queries can cause real problems and your proposed solution is broader than the exact scenario that you first described (consider that some zone that you do not actually have could be delegated to your nameserver, whether by accident or intentionally).

Not responding to queries is generally not seen as good practice for authoritative nameservers. Reasons for this include:

- Resolver servers track the responsiveness/reliability of the authoritative servers they are dealing with to improve their own responsiveness. This is done on a server-by-server basis, not a query-by-query basis. Ie, you may hurt the current perceived reliability of your nameserver if you end up not responding to (potentially misdirected) queries from legitimate sources. It may be possible to trick resolvers into considering your nameserver to be outright down (temporarily, but possibly over and over)
- If not responding can also end up affecting "good" queries (maybe based on high query rate, for instance?), that can cause additional problems that may not be obvious at a first glance, like increased risk of successful cache-poisoning attacks for any unsigned zones that you serve (particularly if an attacker can induce your query dropping somewhat reliably)

Instead, you generally want to limit the size of the responses as to not actually provide the amplification sought by attackers (which it sounds like you are already doing):

- Queries that match no zone (like in your example) should get an empty `REFUSED` response (back in the day it was common to send a full referral response for the root)
- Implementing rate limiting, you probably want to send empty truncated (`TC` set) responses rather than not responding, where if an actual legitimate resolver server ends up rate-limited, they do get a response and it being flagged as truncated just triggers them to resend their query over TCP instead
- The `ANY` query type has limited actual usefulness in the first place, and is sometimes further limited in the interest of avoiding ways of generating large responses. (Like [`minimal-any`](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#boolean-options) in BIND)
- (And of course, absolutely not allowing recursion for the internet at large)

As for not responding with BIND, the feature that does allow for not responding is response rate-limiting (RRL), which has a `slip` configuration parameter to control the ratio of truncating vs dropping when someone has reached the rate-limit. However, do note that dropping is mostly relevant for a resolver server rather than for an authoritative server (as per the earlier explanation).
This is also noted in [RRL section of the BIND manual](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#response-rate-limiting):

> (Note: dropped responses from an authoritative server may reduce the difficulty of a third party successfully forging a response to a recursive resolver. The best security against forged responses is for authoritative operators to sign their zones using DNSSEC and for resolver operators to validate the responses. When this is not an option, operators who are more concerned with response integrity than with flood mitigation may consider setting slip to 1, causing all rate-limited responses to be truncated rather than dropped. This reduces the effectiveness of rate-limiting against reflection attacks.)

If you are in a dire situation where a different tradeoff actually makes sense, you may consider the `slip` knob mentioned above anyway, or some tool with a different set of rate limiting knobs, such as [`dnsdist`](https://dnsdist.org/).
However, if this is just about the normal levels of background noise, you are probably causing new problems for little gain by trying to address it.

Comment: Good points, already using slip to truncate responses. I don't understand the part `some zone that you do not actually have could be delegated to your nameserver, whether by accident or intentionally`.

Comment: @Nozz The point is that if you or someone else were to delegate (by adding `NS`) some name  for which you have no zone to your nameserver, you could get the same kind of "bad" queries from legitimate resolvers.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.